# What's the ultimate way to install debug Flash Player in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, development, debug, flash

What's the easiest way to get a **debug** Flash Player (the one you can [download from here](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html), though I don't care if it's downloaded automatically) working in Firefox?

- 64 bit system, default Firefox from repository
- If possible, I don't want the flash player to be replaced by a newer but non-debug version automatically (updating to a new debug version is ok)
- Want the most recent version (10.2 at the moment)

Comment: I'd like to know this as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the links from the site you provided, download "For Other Linux (.tar.gz).  Once you download it, untar it, `tar xvf install_flash_player_11_linux.i386.tar.gz` (or whatever version you downloaded, then copy the .so into the right directory `sudo cp libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/mozilla/plugins`.  Then restart firefox and it should be fine